# SQL Server Import & Export Wizard Crashes When Choosing Excel File As Data Source

Tags: sql-server, excel, import, crash, ssms

I frequently use the Import Wizard to insert Excel data into tables in SQL, and suddenly the Import Wizard is crashing. I select an Excel file and the second I hit Next the wizard locks up then closes itself after about 30 seconds. I have reinstalled SSMS completely and have run the repair for Office 2019, to no avail.

I've checked Event Viewer and it generates 3 errors. The first is a .NET Runtime error with the following details:

```
Application: DTSWizard.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c06d007e, exception address 769AA6F2
```

The next 2 are both Application Errors which are very similar. The first is:

```
Faulting application name: DTSWizard.exe, version: 15.0.2000.162, time stamp: 0x606e8728
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1023, time stamp: 0xcbf6f7d1
Exception code: 0xc06d007e
Fault offset: 0x0012a6f2
Faulting process ID: 0x244
Faulting application start time: 0x01d767797bed8aa2
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\DTSWizard.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: 287c5a71-552a-4d49-8594-456dd32cf17c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The second is virtually identical except the exception code is 0xc000041d.

I've tested an export to excel and that works fine. It happens to every excel file I try.

Comment: On the "Choose a Data Source" page of the wizard there are about seven versions/formats of Excel files to choose from. Are you selecting the correct version there?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I had to reinstall Access Database Engine, though I was getting an error about having "Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit Registration" installed. Found the steps below to uninstall that, then after installing Access Database Engine all was sorted.

```
1. Press Win + R to open the Run window, type "installer" and click Enter to open the folder in File Explorer.
2. Add the column "Subject". Right click the column headers, then click More and select Subject
3. Sort on the Subject column and scroll down until you locate the name "Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit Registration".
4. Right click the MSI file and choose uninstall.
```